# Not able to find any consumer group in Kafka while using Burrow

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

I am getting the following response when I hit /v2/kafka/local/consumer:

{
"error": false,
"message": "consumer list returned",
"consumers": [],
"request": {
"url": "/v2/kafka/local/consumer",
"host": "EN-NavneetJ",
"cluster": "local",
"group": "",
"topic": ""
}
}
My config file is below:

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmiYT.png)

when I run bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
I get the following consumer groups..

console-consumer-98785
console-consumer-1054
console-consumer-70637
console-consumer-69177
console-consumer-16166
console-consumer-62362
console-consumer-24827
console-consumer-12034
console-consumer-72951

Why am I not able to get this list in burrow.

Also I am not able to get lag or other details for these consumer groups on burrow.

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 1):

The console consumer uses the old consumer and creates groups in ZooKeeper by default. Burrow assumes the new consumer and expects the groups to be in Kafka.

Check if you can run the console consumer with --new flag so it will use the new consumer and therefore work with Burrow.